# How to find the folder from which a PHP command line script was launched?

Tags: php, command-line, command-line-interface, pwd, working-directory

Let's say I have the following folder structure on my hard-drive:

```
/some/dir/
    .
    scripts/
        myfile.php
```

Then from '/some/dir/', I run the following command:

```
/some/dir/$ php scripts/myfile.php
```

Then, in PHP, how can I find the folder from which the command was launched (i.e. '/some/dir')?

I've tried with `getcwd()` and `shell_exec('pwd')` but they both only return the path of the PHP script (i.e. /some/dir/scripts). Any idea how to do this?

Comment: /usr/share/nginx/www/stackoverflow/test.php
<?php echo getcwd();?> Code in test.php
/usr/share/nginx$ php www/stackoverflow/test.php
it return /usr/share/nginx 
It is working what you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can refer, for example, to `$_SERVER['PWD']` and `$_SERVER['OLDPWD']`

For example, I have script `test.php` in `./dev` subfolder with contents:

```
var_dump($_SERVER['PWD'], $_SERVER['OLDPWD']);
```

So, you can see:

```
user@host:/var/www/data$ php dev/test.php       
string(13) "/var/www/data"
string(17) "/var/www/data/dev"
```

So, first one is what you're looking for.

Script full name, as usual, will be available in `__FILE__` constant.